# Proof that equicontinous and suriective dynamical system is distal

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Let us have dynamical system $(X,f)$ (what means that $X$ is compact metric space with metric $d$ and $f: X \to X$ is continuous function). Moreover $f$ is surjective and equicontinous so when we take $x,y \in X$ we have $\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists \delta > 0 \ \forall \ n \in \mathbb{N}: d(x,y) < \delta \Rightarrow d(f^n(x),f^n(y)) < \epsilon$. I want to show that such dynamical system is distal, so  it does not contain proximal pair $\{x,y\}$ such that $x \ne y$ and $\lim \inf_{n \to \infty} d(f^n(x),f^n(y)) = 0$. My idea of proof is to take increasing sequence $n_k$ such that $\lim_{k \to \infty}d(f^{n_k}(x),f^{n_k}(y)) = 0$. This is of course equivalent to definition of proximal pair. Then using assumptions I want to show that $x = y$. Of course $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists n_k \ d(f^{n_k}(x),f^{n_k}(y)) < \epsilon $. I have also suriectivity of $f$. I have problem though with formal proof. I wolud be grateful for any hint.

Comment: If we are allowed to consider the backwards orbits as forming an equicontinuous family then the claim is obvious since if there were such a proximal pair $\{x,y\}$ then the family would fail to satisfy the definition of equicontinuous when we look at $\epsilon=d(x,y)/2$ or something to this effect (a contradiction when we allow this consideration to be an assumption).

Comment: If I take backwards orbit $x, x_1, x_2,...$ and $y, y_1, y_2,...$ ($f(x_n) = x_{n-1}$ect.) and take $\epsilon = \frac{d(x,y)}{2}$ I can find some $\delta$ but how do I know that there exists $x_i, y_i$ from those orbits such that $d(x_i,y_i) < \delta$. This is implied by proximality of $x,y$?

Comment: I gave an answer which I was reluctant to write down previously because it does require this additional assumption which does not appear in the statement of your question. I would have to think about whether the compactness of $X$ allows us to establish the same result without requiring this addiontal assumption. If this turns out to be the case, then I will either delete or edit my answer depending on whether or not someone is kind of enough to provide us with further insight before I am able to find the time to consider things further on my own.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above, suppose the family of functions $\{f^{-n}: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is equicontinuous on $X$.

Assume we have $x,y \in X$ such that $x\neq y$ and $\underset{n\to \infty}\liminf d(f^n(x),f^n(y)) = 0$. So there is a sequence of natural numbers $\{n_k\}$ such that $d\left(f^{n_k}(x),f^{n_k}(y)\right)<\delta$ for all $\delta>0$.

Let $x_k:=f^{n_k}(x)$ and $y_k:=f^{n_k}(y)$   $\, (k=1,2,\ldots)$.

Let $\delta>0$ be given. So we have $d\left(x_k,y_k\right)<\delta$ and $d\left(f^{-n_k}(x_k),f^{-n_k}(y_k)\right)=d(x,y)>0$.

Comment: I suppose it is worth pointing out that this also requires assuming that $f$ is injective as well.